# Toggling of D flip flop

Tags: flipflop

[image]

To divide the frequency of green signal into half, I use D flip flop to generate the blue signal. I need to generate blue signal which is aligned with yellow signal. However, since the green and blue signal is continuous and i cannot control where blue signal start to toggle.In the end, the blue signal is flipped as shown in red dotted line.So, what I need to do to get my desired signal?

Comment: If you know when the yellow pulses always start (or are close) relative to the rising or falling edge of the clock, then you can simply use Q or _Q, but if the pulses occur on the rising edge and, sometimes, on the falling edge, then you can't even use the divided frequency to synchronize the two signals, it's mathematically impossible, unless you *know* when the pulses occur, in which case you can use a multiplexer to simply switch between Q and _Q when needed (but this will break the frequency's linearity).

Comment: I want to make rising edge of yellow signal same as the rising edge of blue signal but I don't know when the blue signal start to high or low.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what you need to do...could you please explain what are the various waveforms? Why there are multiple ones with the same color?

Comment: You can't make the output signal aligned with the yellow signal backwards in time, but how a bout resetting the FF by the high (or low-to-high) of the yellow signal to make it aligned from then on?

Comment: @Vlad, the problem sounds like its not that OP doesn't know when the yellow pulse will arrive, but he doesn't know whether the Q signal will start out at high or low state after power up. (or if OP didn't see this problem in simulation, he should be prepared for it in the real circuit).

Answer (score 1):

The following may at first glance appear to be gobbledygook but, as long as there are no brain-typos it should make sense if worried enough:

Any one of the following solutions is almost easier to implement than to explain :-).

You can produce a (Yellow) AND (NOT_Blue) signal (conceptually one AND gate and one inverter) and then sample the AND gate output on the falling edge of the Green signal. Any time that you get a logical true / high / 1 from the AND gate you need to invert the blue signal. You can do this by resetting or setting the divide flip flop. This will drop into sync on the first non match and stay in synch thereafter if your yellow signal can only occur every second half cycle of the blue signal.

If the yellow signal is able to originate completely randomly relative to blue  signal polarity then it is able to drop out of sync randomly. The above gating will drive it back into sync half way through the next mismatched half cycle.

If you want it to resynchronise as soon as possible you can use a very slightly delayed rising edge of yellow to sample blue and to set blue high if it is low at this point.  This leads to a sudden inversion of blue so you get a double length blue high with a small negative going spike in the middle.

For extra points you can do similar to the above but arrange the actually seen blue signal to be produced only once the yellow rising egde test has been done. What is then seen externally is that any time blue is out of sync with yellow it just extends at the yellow rising edge and stays high for a double period, thus dropping back into sync.

If the double period blue high is not acceptable then you can do the test when blue is high but eg carry the change over until a later point - eg extend the next blue low to double length.

If introducing any asymmetry in blue is unacceptable then you need to start the system correctly. Assuming that blue does not generate yellow then at initialisation you can hold the blue flipflop and then when a yellow rising edge occurs you allow blue to run, starting with a high half cycle.

Note that the introduction of asynchronous timing delays into a digital clocked system will have purists screaming in horror. It should be possible to carry out all actions synchronously at (not near) clock edge changes BUT this may introduce a clock cycls delay before the system resyncs compared with a delay implemented asynchronous solution.

The usual cautions apply re being careful not to introduce race hazards with async delays, BUT this is liable to be of low risk here.

Any one of the above solutions is almost easier to implement than to explain :-).

.